# How to handle Data deletion inside a TextBox using Mouse?

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where I need to show a button labeled `Set` only when both the text in two separate Text input fields are the same.

If the text in the two fields is the same, I am able to show/hide the Set Button .

However I am failing at this below negative test Scenario

**Scenario** :

If the text in two fields is the same, I am showing the Set Button.
However assuming that data is selected by the Mouse and deleted, the Set button is being still shown ??

Please let me know how to handle this scenario

This is my code .

```
<input type="text" id="fort1text" class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="">
<input type="text" id="fort2text" class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="">
<input type="button" id="setcategory" value="Set ">
<input type="button" id="validate" value="Validate">

$(function () {
    $("#setcategory").hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '#validate', function (event) {
    var val1 = $("#fort1text").val();
    var val2 = $("#fort2text").val();
    if(val1!=''&&val2!='')
    {
    if(val1==val2)
    {
$("#setcategory").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#setcategory").hide();
    }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tf2ykphz/1/

Comment: It isn't clear how to reproduce the problem.  Can you expand on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other event handlers for the input such as input, propertychanged and paste. For example:

```
$('#fort1text, #fort2text').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    ...
});
```

Using this example, the button will only show with both input boxes have exactly the same values.

Working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzcfmqmw/):

Comment: I have also cleaned up the code a bit, how I would do it. But you can change it back to how your example is formed.